# Upload 360 video with Vimeo API

Tags: node.js, video, upload, vimeo, vimeo-api

I'm trying to upload a 360° video on Vimeo using the API.
According to the [documentation](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/endpoints/videos#PATCH/videos/%7Bvideo_id%7D), my request is the following:

PATCH  `https://api.vimeo.com/videos/<vimeo_video_id>`
HEADER Authorization 
BODY

```
{
    name:'[TEST_VR] TEST VR mono',
    spatial:{
        stereo_format: 'mono',
    }
}
```

also tried

```
    {
    name:'[TEST_VR] TEST VR mono',
    spatial:{
        stereo_format: 'mono',
        projection: 'equirectangular',
    }
}
```

The video is uploaded with the right name but as a normal video, not 360°.
Where I'm wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try also sending a value for `spatial.projection`.

Comment: Thank you, tried yet but nothing change. I'm editing my question!

Answer (score 0):

I think your question was answered in the Vimeo API Help Forum, but in case it's useful to anyone here:

It looks like your JSON is invalid. Make sure you wrap the keys in quotations as well as the values. Additionally, remove the hanging comma after the last value in the array. The code below should work:

Link: developer.vimeo.com/api/start#parameters

```
{
"spatial":{
"stereo_format": "mono",
"projection": "equirectangular"
}
}
```